# Firebase AsyncSnapshot, length of documents?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, snapshot

I need the length of Firebase documents for my app to make a ListView of them, but for some reason the data.docs cannot be found, even though the official Firebase website says it should (https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore-odm/references/). I tried everything, using documents keyword instead, using snapshot.requireData, but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Hello, are you querying more than one document or a single document?

Comment: I wonder if it needs some typing.  What if you change your `StreamBuilder` to `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`?

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMWBA.png)

use this way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).